# How to cache UIWebView page for all session

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, uiwebview, nsurlcache

I would like to load page first time from web and other time from cache when there is no change in page.

I have some problems with cache.

I paste this code in AppDelegate:

```
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:20 * 1024 * 1024
                                                        diskCapacity:100 * 1024 * 1024
                                                            diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
```

and this how I use request:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:dataURLString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:2*60];
```

If I stay in app it works fine and page load from cache, but when I close my app and load it again, page load from web again. What I have to do, to load it from cache?

Comment: so the cache is cleared out when you quit the app ?

Comment: @Mr.T yes after close application, cache storage is released

Comment: @Apple say : "In iOS, the on-disk cache may be purged when the system runs low on disk space, but only when your app is not running."

Comment: @Mr.T it's purged from simulator, i think he has enough disk space, if I have 400+Gb free space

Comment: cache also gets removed when app is not running!!!

Comment: @Mr.T and there is no way to save it?

Comment: did you try SDURLCache ?

Comment: @Mr.T no, I will try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SDURLCache` is a drop in replacement for NSURLCache but does save to disk on iOS 4 and above.

```
- (void)prepareCache {
    SDURLCache *cache = [[SDURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:4 * 1024 * 1024
                                                      diskCapacity:20 * 1024 * 1024
                                                          diskPath:[SDURLCache defaultCachePath]];
    cache.minCacheInterval = 0;
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:cache];
    NSLog(@"Cache is being logged to: %@", [SDURLCache defaultCachePath]);
}
```

MOre info can be found [here:](http://www.nsscreencast.com/episodes/15-http-caching)